# Make a Custom template for a specific category in wordpress

Tags: plugins, categories, menus, templates, link-category

I am having issue with a custom category template. I want to create a new template for my specific category "VIDEOS" so that all posts under this category show in new style. Basically, i want to show posts with videos in a new way as 3 posts in one row with featured images and a featured slider on top of that page showing 4 new posts of that category ?

But i am confused... Can i do this in wordpress ? Because my home page also has a featured slider. Can i create a new slider for that page template but one thing is sure. I need to work with only one category for that custom template i.e. videos.........

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use a custom name for your template and style it as you need,

take a look at the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates